# U.S. universities on-campus residence for International PhD students?

Tags: phd, united-states, international-students, abroad

I want to ask generally, do most U.S. universities offer on-campus accommodation for International Ph.D. students **Who are married**?

If the student is benefitted from scholarships `{Free tuition and fees + 2k monthly stipend}` will he/she need to pay an extra to use not-shared on-campus settlements?

Without any self-funding and other support, is the stipend enough to pay for it while taking care of food, health care, etc. at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to ask generally, do most U.S. universities offer on-campus accommodation for International Ph.D. students Who are married?

Probably not. Even when available, it might not be your best option. In some places on-campus housing can be a fair bit more expensive than renting from a private landlord. And if the university offers subsidized housing (whether on or away from the main campus) the waiting period can be quite long. Basically, you'd want to research your alternatives once you know where you might be going.

> If the student is benefitted from scholarships {Free tuition and fees + 2k monthly stipend} will he/she need to pay an extra to use not-shared on-campus settlements?

Generally, housing wouldn't be free, but possibly subsidized.

> Without any self-funding and other support, is the stipend enough to pay for it while taking care of food, health care, etc. at the same time?

It varies, so it's hard to say anything concretely. If the university pays for health insurance, that can be worth a lot actually. Also, living expenses vary considerably from place to place. I will say that if you have to pay for insurance yourself, and pay rent in a large popular city, well, money could be very tight.

Again, this is something you'll have to research when considering your offers. There are websites that help you compare these expenses between cities, to see if e.g. rent is particularly expensive somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you do the following search on Google, you will find some universities that do: "married student housing for graduate students". But I doubt that *most* do and the ones that provide this service would be large universities. Housing isn't free, of course, but it can be priced fairly low. It is possible that it is market priced in some places and provided only for convenience, but I think that it is most likely subsidized by the university nearly everywhere it is offered.

I took advantage of this long ago so my experience is likely no longer valid, but the search will get you started. In my case it was very very low and included all utilities.

Comment: Without any financial support, is the stipend enough to pay for it while taking care of food, health care, etc.?

Comment: It is impossible to say. Note that a university big enough to provide a housing option will probably also have a fairly low cost medical insurance program. The US is a very expensive country generally, of course. You will have to do your own math.

Comment: In my limited experience, it has actually been the smaller schools that have provided more generous housing, often if they are in smaller towns and there's nowhere to live, versus universities in large cities where there are many options.